# how to get dynamically read files and write files from sdcard

Tags: android, android-manifest

hi all i used below code for getting sdcard files but it shows no application perform this action. how can dynamically get the sdcard directory files to read files and write files without using android widget help me to avoid the problem

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open PDF"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting  **no application perform this action**  because any of the installed  applications can not perform that action.

Seems that you are running this on an emulator, which does not include a pdf reader.